# How to accept request params as well as json body input in SpringMVC?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

What I would like to have:

1. Ability to send use query params as input.
2. Ability to send use url-form-encoded params as input;
3. Ability to use all the things that WebBinder can do for me (including both above)
4. Abiity to use JSON body as input;
5. Ability to use validation

Righ now I am doing so by creating 2 separate handler methods like this

```
@PutMapping("doIt")  //this handles all 1-3 variats that I have in min
public MyResp doIt(@Valid MyDot dto){
   return doStuff(dto);
}


@PutMapping("doIt",consumes=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) // this handles 4
public MyResp doIt(@RequestBody @Valid MyDot dto){
   return this.doIt(dto);//Just delegate!
}


class MyDto{
   @NotNull
   String name;   //and other fields with other constraints
}
```

This works as expected, but it feels like alot of boilerplate. Is there away to do it simpler?

I could do it like this

```
 public MyResp doIt(@RequestBody(required=false) MyDot bodyDto, MyDto dto)
```

but then it is not possible to use validation as one or the other (or both) arguments will be invalid.